# Specific server not responding specifically for me

Tags: steam, team-fortress-2

There are a few community servers, in specific three from the same host, that I want to connect to badly but the game always says "Server not responding". I'm not banned from them and everyone else can connect just fine. But I just can't do it. Someone told me to try and connect to the server through Steam's server list in the "View" option, but it shows the same message ("Server not responding").

I've already tried turning off the Firewall. Verifying the game's integrity. Reinstalling the game. Setting launch option and typing the `+clientport` command. Nothing worked.

I really only want to join the IP `200.98.149.240:27015`, but it's among the ones that simply aren't responding.

Looking around I've only found one other person with this problem, on a post from 2 years ago, and there wasn't any mention on how to fix this.

Comment: Have you tried turning your internet off and on again? | Have you tried enabling ports (disabling the firewall) on your router (if it does block by default)? | Can you connect to other servers?

Comment: Yes, I've turned internet off and on again; this has been going on for months now. | I haven't tried that, I'd do so tomorrow, I actually don't even know how to do that. I suppose a quick Google search gotta do the trick? If not so...could you explain what you mean by "enabling ports on my router"? | Yes, there are a ton of servers I can connect to, but some I just...can't. Also I may as well add the fact that I COULD join said servers before, and after no significant (or at least none intentional) change I simply couldn't anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Try `connect 200.98.149.240:27015` from TF2 console